# How to make autocomplate?

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, ajax, django

I have form with 2 fields.

First field `user_characteristic` is `СhoiseField` and the second field `description` is simple `Textarea`.

I want autocomplate second field when user select some value from first field.

I use JQuery UI autocomplete. Here below you can see my code. Where I did mistake?

**forms.py:**

```
RequirementForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Requirement
        fields = ('user_characteristic', 'description',)
        widgets = {
            'user_characteristic': forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'id': 'user-characteristic',}),
        }

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(RequirementForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['user_characteristic'] = forms.ChoiceField(
            choices=[(x.user_symbol, x.user_class) for x in UserCharacteristic.objects.all()],
        )
        self.fields['description'].widget = Textarea(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'id': 'description',})
```

**views.py:**

```
def requirement_autocomplete(request):
    if request.is_ajax():
        word = request.GET.get('term', '')
        user_characteristics = UserCharacteristic.objects.filter(user_class__icontains=word)
        results = []
        for user_characteristic in user_characteristics:
            user_characteristic_json = {
                'id': user_characteristic.id,
                'label': user_characteristic.user_class,
                'value': user_characteristic.user_class,
                'user_characteristic_description': user_characteristic.user_symbol + ' – Варианты использования для роли ' + user_characteristic.user_description
            }
            results.append(user_characteristic_json)
        data = json.dumps(results)
    else:
        data = 'fail'
    mimetype = 'application/json'
    return HttpResponse(data, mimetype)
```

**javascript:**

```
$("#user-characteristic").autocomplete({
   source: "/requirement_autocomplete/",
   minLength: 0,
   select: function( event, ui ){
      $("#user-characteristic").val(ui.item.value);
      $("#description").val(ui.item.user_characteristic_description);
       return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: Why not use some libs, e.g.: [ajax-select](https://github.com/crucialfelix/django-ajax-selects)?

Comment: @vanadium23 Hello! Thank you for this link. I need autocomplate second field (Textarea) by the value of selected item in first field (ChoiceField). Is it possible with this lib? Can you show me little example pls. It seems like this lib works only in admin. Is it true?

Comment: please check this answer you can use django auto complete light http://stackoverflow.com/a/41541942/2955584